# the scope of AOP

Tags: java, aop

I'd like to know peoples' preference on applying AOP.

For instance. if hit count should be increased upon reading an article, Should I apply AOP to view method? Or just call the increaseHitCount() within view()?

In my point of view on this matter, I guess increaseHitCount() isn't a main purpose of view() method but ancillary matter.

```
public DAO dao;

public Article view() {
    dao.increaseHitCount(); //<-- I think this is not for here.

    return dao.getArticle();
}
```

However, I'm just worrying that the code is getting hard to understand and read by AOPs applied throughout the sources.

Comment: This question could be improved if you were to give a concrete example of what you're trying to do (with code, preferably). Otherwise, this question may be closed as "not constructive" as [per the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Ok, I'll make it better! thank you for comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AOP will help you make your code more orthogonal, and also helps fighting code duplication. My experience is that aspects are used for general system-wise features. Think about whether the hit count is loosely coupled to the rest of the page logic or not and is it general enough. If yes is acceptable (or preferable) to use it as an aspect. On the other hand AOP brings overhead, but AspectJ for instance is really fast.

I this case I would consider AOP if it is otherwise used in the project.

Comment: Thanks you It helped a lot of my thinking of AOP

Answer (score 1):

AOP aims to enable a better separation of [cross-cutting concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern). In this case you are dealing with two concerns: the article view and the statics on clicks count. You should therefore separate them. As you can not properly separate them only through OOP constructs (your view method will always have to know there is something to be executed before returning the view) AOP is the right solution. 
Many however think code becomes hard to understand. That almost depends on how much and how well you use it, also it may depend on the quality of the underlying OO architecture